# API monitoring tool

Tags: django, azure, django-rest-framework, sysdig

I wish to monitor all the APIs that I created on one of my docker containers. That Docker container is using Django REST framework for its services.. and I am running it on Azure. I want to monitor my API by means of if it is working or if there are too many requests it will throw an alert.. what is its request per second something like that.

We are using sysdig for monitoring our containers but I don't think it has the capability to monitor all our APIs of our Django Rest Framework

Comment: Are you looking for something installable (in which case you need to worry about *that* falling over), or available as a service (e.g. someone else runs the monitoring service, and lets you know when your API is down)?

Comment: either way will do..

Answer (score 1):

To monitor your API performance and downtime, you could create custom scripts to ping your API and alert you if there's downtime, or you could use a third-party service to monitor remotely. This is the simpler option, as it doesn't require writing and maintaining code.

One third-party service you could use is mine, https://assertible.com. They provide frequent health checks (1/5/15 minute), deep data validation, integrations with other services like Slack and GitHub, and a nice way to view/manage test failures.

If you want to integrate with your own code or scripts, you can use Trigger URLs and/or the Deployments API to programatically run your tests whenever and wherever:

```
$ curl 'https://assertible.com/apis/{API_ID}/run?api_token=ABC'
[{
  "runId": "test_fjdmbd",
  "result": "TestPass",
  "assertions": {
      "passed": [{...}],
      "failed": [{...}]
  },
  ...
}]
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Oh and since you also mentioned monitoring the _resources_ on the server: I would recommend going with a third-party service here as well. One of the more popular ones is [Nagios](https://nagios.org), so you can check that out and look for similar tools if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the monitoring functionality from Postman. For more information check out the following link [1].

[1] https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/monitors/intro_monitors/

Answer (score 0):

Since you're running on Azure, you should take a look at [Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/):

> Application Insights is an extensible Application Performance
>   Management (APM) service for web developers on multiple platforms. Use
>   it to monitor your live web application. It will automatically detect
>   performance anomalies. It includes powerful analytics tools to help
>   you diagnose issues and to understand what users actually do with your
>   app. It's designed to help you continuously improve performance and
>   usability. It works for apps on a wide variety of platforms including
>   .NET, Node.js and J2EE, hosted on-premises or in the cloud. It
>   integrates with your devOps process, and has connection points to a
>   variety of development tools. [Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-overview)

API monitoring is described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-monitor-web-app-availability).

Comment: Added a link to API monitoring documentation.

Comment: Ok, I'll try this one out